# How do I prove that $\mathcal{H}$, with $\mathcal{VC}$ dimension $d$, shatters all subsets with size less than $d-1$?

Tags: proofs, computational-learning-theory, vc-dimension, vc-theory, hypothesis-class

If a certain hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ has a $\mathcal{VC}$ dimension $d$ over a domain $X$, how can I prove that $H$ will shatter all subsets of $X$ with size less than $d$, i.e. $\mathcal{H}$ will shatter $A \subset X$ where $|A| \leq d-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can show that it is not true by a counterexample. For example, $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\mathcal H = \{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ is the finite set hypothesis class. By definition, in this case, the $\mathcal{VC}$ dimension of $\mathcal H$ over the domain $X$ is $d=2$. Although $A = \{3\} \subset X$, whose size is smaller than the $\mathcal{VC}$ dimension, i.e $|A|<d=2$, it is not shattered by $\mathcal H$.